# Parsing Json in Python for root element

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Here is my JSON string which I need to parse.

```
{
  "192.168.1.2_151b3a32-ce00-114a-e000-0004a50c1c6d_stream1" : {
    "@class" : "com.barco.compose.media.transcode.internal.h264.H264Gateway",
    "id" : "192.168.1.2_151b3a32-ce00-114a-e000-0004a50c1c6d_stream1",
    "uri" : {
      "high" : "rtp://239.1.1.2:5006",
      "low" : "rtp://239.1.1.1:5006"
    },
    "owner" : {
      "@class" : "com.barco.compose.media.transcode.Acma",
      "source" : "dvi1-1-mna-1890322558",
      "stream" : "udp://239.1.1.7:5004",
      "type" : "video",
      "resolution" : [ 1, 1 ],
      "framerateDivider" : [ 1, 1 ],
      "profile" : [ "baseline" ],
      "output" : [ "high", "low" ],
      "destination" : [ "", "" ],
      "ipvsProfile" : "high",
      "ipvsSDP" : [ "" ],
      "ipvsTitle" : "DiORStream",
      "ipvsTagName" : [ "" ],
      "ipvsTagValue" : [ "" ],
      "ipvsDescription" : "NMSDesc",
      "ipvsHLS" : true
    },
    "type" : "video"
  },
  "192.168.1.2_151b3a32-ce00-114a-e000-0004a50c1c6d_stream2" : {
    "@class" : "com.barco.compose.media.transcode.internal.h264.H264Gateway",
    "id" : "192.168.1.2_151b3a32-ce00-114a-e000-0004a50c1c6d_stream2",
    "uri" : {
      "high" : "rtp://239.1.1.4:5006",
      "low" : "rtp://239.1.1.3:5006"
    },
    "owner" : {
      "@class" : "com.barco.compose.media.transcode.Acma",
      "source" : "dvi1-1-mna-1890322558",
      "stream" : "udp://239.1.1.7:5004",
      "type" : "video",
      "resolution" : [ 1, 1 ],
      "framerateDivider" : [ 1, 1 ],
      "profile" : [ "baseline" ],
      "output" : [ "high", "low" ],
      "destination" : [ "", "" ],
      "ipvsProfile" : "high",
      "ipvsSDP" : [ "" ],
      "ipvsTitle" : "nikhil",
      "ipvsTagName" : [ "" ],
      "ipvsTagValue" : [ "" ],
      "ipvsDescription" : "nikhilDesc",
      "ipvsHLS" : true
    },
    "type" : "video"
  }
}
```

Now I want to get value of "id". I have used [jsonpath-rw library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonpath-rw) for Python, but that is not working. If I use `*` whole response gets printed. Looks like the whole response is root. I have used different combinations on http://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/, such as `*.id`, `$[0].id`.

Comment: You don't seem to have a root id element, just ids in the sub-elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JSON` object contains several root (or top) objects indexed with keys such as `"192.168.1.2_151b3a32-ce00-114a-e000-0004a50c1c6d_stream1"`. From your question it seems you want to access the `id` field of these elements. For that the simple way is probably using the `json` module - included in the standard library - to load the string and then access the `id` of each element.

```
import json
my_json_string = "..."
my_json_dict = json.loads(my_json_string)
for key, value in my_json_dict.items():
    print("Id is {} for item {}".format(value["id"], key))
```

However if you just want the keys of your `JSON` object all you need is

```
import json
my_json_string = "..."
my_json_dict = json.loads(my_json_string)
print(["Got item with id '{}'".format(key) for key in d.keys()])
```

Comment: Well how can I get one "id", using above code gives me both id which is good, but how can I have one value at a time.

Comment: `d.keys()` returns a list-like object that supports operations like membership test and iteration so if you want to access any element using the following code: `d.keys()[1]` to get the first "id"

Answer (score 0):

The following expression is what you need:

```
$..id
```

Proof:

```
In [12]: vv = json.loads(my_input_string)

In [13]: jsonpath_expr = parse('$..id')

In [14]: [x.value for x in jsonpath_expr.find(vv)]
Out[14]: 
[u'192.168.1.2_151b3a32-ce00-114a-e000-0004a50c1c6d_stream1',
 u'192.168.1.2_151b3a32-ce00-114a-e000-0004a50c1c6d_stream2']
```

However, *please be careful*, when using `..` operator, since it does deep scan. It means if there is any other object inside your JSON with `id` field, value of this field will also be added to result of query.

Comment: I tried this, but I want single value at a time, don't know how useful is the utility JSON_PATH RW

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a base/root element - just a collection of keys and values.

You can iterate through them with something like this:

```
import json
import pprint

values = json.loads(YOUR_JSON_STRING)

for v in values:
    print v, pprint.pprint(values[v])
```

That will print out the following two elements (each with it's own key) in the resulting JSON object:

```
192.168.1.2_151b3a32-ce00-114a-e000-0004a50c1c6d_stream1{u'@class': u'com.barco.compose.media.transcode.internal.h264.H264Gateway',
 u'id': u'192.168.1.2_151b3a32-ce00-114a-e000-0004a50c1c6d_stream1',
 u'owner': {u'@class': u'com.barco.compose.media.transcode.Acma',
            u'destination': [u'', u''],
            u'framerateDivider': [1, 1],
            u'ipvsDescription': u'NMSDesc',
            u'ipvsHLS': True,
            u'ipvsProfile': u'high',
            u'ipvsSDP': [u''],
            u'ipvsTagName': [u''],
            u'ipvsTagValue': [u''],
            u'ipvsTitle': u'DiORStream',
            u'output': [u'high', u'low'],
            u'profile': [u'baseline'],
            u'resolution': [1, 1],
            u'source': u'dvi1-1-mna-1890322558',
            u'stream': u'udp://239.1.1.7:5004',
            u'type': u'video'},
 u'type': u'video',
 u'uri': {u'high': u'rtp://239.1.1.2:5006', u'low': u'rtp://239.1.1.1:5006'}}
 None
192.168.1.2_151b3a32-ce00-114a-e000-0004a50c1c6d_stream2{u'@class': u'com.barco.compose.media.transcode.internal.h264.H264Gateway',
 u'id': u'192.168.1.2_151b3a32-ce00-114a-e000-0004a50c1c6d_stream2',
 u'owner': {u'@class': u'com.barco.compose.media.transcode.Acma',
            u'destination': [u'', u''],
            u'framerateDivider': [1, 1],
            u'ipvsDescription': u'nikhilDesc',
            u'ipvsHLS': True,
            u'ipvsProfile': u'high',
            u'ipvsSDP': [u''],
            u'ipvsTagName': [u''],
            u'ipvsTagValue': [u''],
            u'ipvsTitle': u'nikhil',
            u'output': [u'high', u'low'],
            u'profile': [u'baseline'],
            u'resolution': [1, 1],
            u'source': u'dvi1-1-mna-1890322558',
            u'stream': u'udp://239.1.1.7:5004',
            u'type': u'video'},
 u'type': u'video',
 u'uri': {u'high': u'rtp://239.1.1.4:5006', u'low': u'rtp://239.1.1.3:5006'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the subject when trying to find a solution for a problem of mine.
In the meantime, I think you found a solution but if anyone is passing by check the jsonlines library that is very useful and could solve the problem
https://jsonlines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

you can get `id` like this(save your json string as a **single line** file as `test.json`):

```
import simplejson as json

with open("test.json") as fp:
    line = fp.readline()
    json = json.loads(line)
    for k,v in json.items():
        print v.get("id","no id found") # no id found is the default value in case there is no id defined
```